How to Customize the Timing of NavigationBar Title Display in SwiftUI
I am looking for a way to customize the display timing of the navigation bar’s title in SwiftUI based on the content.
Specifically, I would like to control when the title appears or disappears as the content scrolls in or out of view, ideally with some animation effects.
I am open to any ideas you may have!
While comparing the Settings app and the Mail app, I noticed that their title display animations differ. This leads me to believe that the behavior might not rely on a built-in API but rather a custom implementation.


If anyone has insights or examples to share, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.
Thank you in advance!

You can listen to content offset of ScrollView and  animate title's opacity in navigation bar base on that in combination with title's frame in ScrollView

See Hide toolbar item on scroll with .toolbarTitleDisplayMode(.inlineLarge) for an example of something similar.
